# Does Kafka notify when a queue reaches certain number of messages?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am planning to use Kafka to store messages in queues and fetch the messages if the number of message in a particular queue reaches some limit (say 1000).

Is there any way in which Kafka server can notify the consumers when queues reach their limits?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question what you are trying to do is retrieve messages once the consumer lag hits a certain value. I don't know of any way to receive notifications from your Kafka cluster. However, you should be able to run the ConsumerOffsetChecker periodically to check lag. Example below from the documentation:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --zkconnect localhost:2181 --group test
Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
my-group        my-topic                       0   0               0               0               test_jkreps-mn-1394154511599-60744496-0
my-group        my-topic                       1   0               0               0               test_jkreps-mn-1394154521217-1a0be913-0
```

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_consumer_lag

You can also try to this info out of Kakfa via JMX:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Operations#Operations-Monitoring